# pandas format datetimeindex to quarters

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, datetime-format

With a resample job, I have my monthly values converted to quarterly values:

```
hs=hs.resample('QS',axis=1).mean()
```

Works well, my columns look like this:

```
hs.columns:
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-04-01', '2000-07-01', '2000-10-01',
           '2001-01-01', '2001-04-01', '2001-07-01', '2001-10-01',
           '2002-01-01', '2002-04-01', '2002-07-01', '2002-10-01',
```

Now I want them to convert in the YYYYq[1-4] format, which I thought should be as easy as (according to this [Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.strftime.html)):

```
hs.columns.strftime('%Yq%q')
```

But that gives:

```
array(['2000qq', '2000qq', '2000qq', '2000qq', '2001qq', '2001qq',
   '2001qq', '2001qq', '2002qq', '2002qq', '2002qq', '2002qq',
   '2003qq', '2003qq', '2003qq', '2003qq', '2004qq', '2004qq',
```

Where do I go wrong and how can i fix this?

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation specifies `strftime` on *Period* data type not *Datetime* data type; To use `%q` formatter, you can convert the datetime Index to Period (days as unit) and then format it:

```
cols = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-04-01', '2000-07-01', '2000-10-01',
                         '2001-01-01', '2001-04-01', '2001-07-01', '2001-10-01',
                         '2002-01-01', '2002-04-01', '2002-07-01', '2002-10-01'])

cols.to_period('D').strftime('%Yq%q')
# hs.columns.to_period('D').strftime('%Yq%q')
#array([u'2000q1', u'2000q2', u'2000q3', u'2000q4', u'2001q1', u'2001q2',
#       u'2001q3', u'2001q4', u'2002q1', u'2002q2', u'2002q3', u'2002q4'],
#      dtype='<U6')
```

Or simply use `to_period` with `Q` (quarter) as unit:

```
cols.to_period('Q')
# hs.columns.to_period('Q')
#PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q2', '2000Q3', '2000Q4', '2001Q1', '2001Q2',
#             '2001Q3', '2001Q4', '2002Q1', '2002Q2', '2002Q3', '2002Q4'],
#            dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

Answer (score 3):

One way it to use [`pd.Series.dt.to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['2000-01-01', '2000-04-01', '2000-07-01', '2000-10-01',
                           '2001-01-01', '2001-04-01', '2001-07-01', '2001-10-01',
                           '2002-01-01', '2002-04-01', '2002-07-01', '2002-10-01'])

df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns.to_series()).dt.to_period('Q')

print(df.columns)

# PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q2', '2000Q3', '2000Q4', '2001Q1', '2001Q2',
#              '2001Q3', '2001Q4', '2002Q1', '2002Q2', '2002Q3', '2002Q4'],
#             dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```